# Merge two configuration files while removing duplicate keys?

Tags: node.js, configuration, sonarqube

So I'm trying to split the following file sonar-project.properties file into two files. One file which I will commit to source control and the other that the developer has on their local machine.

Local developer `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.host.url=localhost
sonar.login=herro
sonar.password=lol
```

`sonar-project.properties` file that will be in source control:

```
sonar.host.url=https://my-project.com/sonarqube
sonar.projectKey=my-project
```

I would like them both merged to result in the following:

```
sonar.host.url=localhost
sonar.projectKey=my-project
sonar.login=herro
sonar.password=lol
```

It's pretty much a "default" configuration that I would like the developer to be able to override with their own configuration values. Afaiac this is not supported natively by SonarQube so I will have to do this manually.

I am using Node.js with developers on both Linux and Windows machines, so both platforms will have to be supported. Any ideas?

Comment: are you limited to some kind of tooling, or how do you execute the sonarqube scanner? does it have to be the scanner, maybe a plugin for the IDE like SonarLint would be also sufficient? depends on the ruleset you are using. Or even using gradle as a build tool? there are multiple ways how this can be achieved.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner I find it weird StackOverflow alerts me 4 hours you post! No tooling is off limits, we do use ESLint with  the SonarQube plugin so we are getting the lint rules, but it's more like the security assessment that is very interesting for us! But as for your question no, no tooling is off limits!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a JS project hence that my suggestion might not be feasible but it would definitely work.

I suggest to use gradle. Downside is you need to have java on your development machines. But starting from there, you have multiple options to achieve this. Additionally you have a gradle sonarqube scanner also, which could make this quiet easy to setup on all machines.

Setting up gradle is fairly easy (this is a short explanation, you want to investigate into gradle wrapper to ensure the same gradle version for all). based on https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube this is all you need within your build.gradle to start. But this is just the beginning.

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
}
```

after that you have multiple options. Developers could specify global sonar credentials within `<user>/.gradle/gradle.properties` or you could simply load two files within the plugin like

```
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            Properties props = new Properties()
            props.load(new FileInputStream("sonar-project.properties"))
            props.forEach { key, value ->
                property key, value
            }
            Properties propsLocal = new Properties()
            propsLocal.load(new FileInputStream("sonar-project-local.properties"))
            propsLocal.forEach { key, value ->
                property key, value
            }
        }
    }
```

with two different files, one checked in, and one locally created.

As i mentioned this is Gradle and relies on Java but as you said every tooling is feasible. i though i suggest this, you can also configure sonarqube gradle to scan you JS files, this works pretty well, as we use it like this within our company. Furthermore we also use gradle to install nodejs with the same version everywhere, which is a nice side effect.